# Throttle/Buffer one Observable collection based on another in Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am trying to thottle the events generated, I am creating a stream that merges two types of events. I am monitoring a set of records and events could fire if

1. CollectionChangedEvent when rows are added/deleted. 
    2. PropertyChangedEvent when one of the item's values changes

```
public IObservable<IEnumerable<ChangeDTO>> GetChangeStream()
{
     IObservable<IEnumerable<ChangeDTO>> allItems = 
     Observable.FromEventPattern<CollectionChangedEventArgs>(
                  x => source.CollectionChanged += x,
                  x => source.CollectionChanged-= x)
                  .Select(i => new ChangeDTO(source.SelectedItems, true, null)})
                  .Buffer(Timespan.FromMilliSeconds(300);                      

     IObservable<IEnumerable<ChangeDTO>> updatedItem = 
     Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
              x => source.PropertyChanged += x,
              x => source.PropertyChanged -= x).
              Select(i => new List<ChangeDTO>() {new ChangeDTO(new[] {source.Item}, false, source.UpdatedProperties)};

    return allItems.Merge(updatedItems);       
}

public class ChangeDTO
{
    ChangeDTO(IEnumerable<SourceDTO> items, bool recalculateAll, IEnumerable<string>   
     propertiesChanged)    
}
```

I am trying to clear the PropertyChangedEvent buffer if CollectionChangedEvent fires in 300 milliseconds period, i.e. not interested in Property Changes and want to ignore them. Property changes are of interest only if no CollectionChangedEvent gets fired.

Comment: Can you explain under what conditions you want the propertychange sequence to push values. Do you just want to stop listening to changes on items that have been removed? Only get updates until the collection change event and then no more?

Comment: @LeeCampbell: Whenever the CollectionChangedEvent is triggered (recalculatedAll = true), any property changes that have been buffered so far in that 300 ms are not required to be processed and can safely ignore them and start buffering new changes. If no CollectionChangedEvent fires in the next 300ms, I want the PropertyChangedEvents buffered to be available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit involved, but I'll try to explain it succinctly!

The core idea is to start with a buffered stream of PropertyChangedEvents(PCE), but then switch to a new buffered stream every time there is a CollectionChangedEvent (CCE). Finally we merge the CCE and flattened buffered stream of PCE together.

We start collectUpdateItems by converting the CCEs to a stream of `Unit.Default` and `StartWith` an initial value (this lets us start collecting PCEs before the first CCE). When then project (`Select`) each pulse into a new buffered stream of PCEs. The `Switch` will ensure only the most recent buffer stream is returned. The `Where` just drops empty buffers.

Finally we `Merge` this with the original CCE stream (projected into single element lists for compatibility with the PCE buffers).

Hope this makes sense!

Modifying your streams slighty to start with plain, unbuffered ChangeDTO object streams:

```
IObservable<IEnumerable<ChangeDTO>> allItems = 
Observable.FromEventPattern<CollectionChangedEventArgs>(
    x => source.CollectionChanged += x,
    x => source.CollectionChanged-= x)
    .Select(i => new ChangeDTO(source.SelectedItems, true, null)});

IObservable<IEnumerable<ChangeDTO>> updatedItem = 
Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
    x => source.PropertyChanged += x,
    x => source.PropertyChanged -= x).
    .Select(i => new ChangeDTO(new[] {source.Item}, false, source.UpdatedProperties));

var collectUpdatedItems = allItems
    // We only need to know the CCE happened, not the details of it, so convert to Units
    .Select(_ => Unit.Default)
    // We must insert an event so PCEs are buffered before the first CCE
    .StartWith(Unit.Default)
    // Here we create a new PCE buffer stream at the start and after each CCE
    .Select(_ => updateItem.Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(300)))
    // On a CCE, switch to the new PCE buffer stream, dropping the current PCE buffer
    .Switch()
    // Finally drop any empty buffers
    .Where(i => i.Count > 0);

// merge the CollectionChangedEvents with the PropertyChangedEvent buffers
return collectionUpdateItems.Merge(allItems.Select(i => new List<ChangeDTO> {i}));
```

Comment: I've not come across a need for this particular construct before; it is quite specific. I'm sure I've used similar ideas elsewhere, but none spring to mind offhand. The use of Switch is the key trick to take away from this I think.